# Why gmail/yahoo / what's app service is not getting killed?

Tags: android

I have an intent service which is continously polling to check if data has been modified in the server. The problem is if the app remains idle for some time , it stops receiving notification. We are suspecting the service has been killed by android.

I think even GCMINTENTSERVICE is also killed by android in some time.

1. My question is how come gmail / what's app/yahoo mail always sync without foreground notification. Which sync mechanism they are using.
2. Are you aware of any other app which is always receiving notification even when in background, so that I can check in Google why it is not killed in some time.
3. Does Google kill gcmintentservice if it has been running for some time in the backgroud.

EDIT: GCMBASEINTENTSERVICE is the service we are planning to implement for push notifications, because with the older polling  service the app did not receive notification after some time. This is may be because it was getting killed by android in some time. So with push notifications,  the app will always receive notification?  Isn't Gcmbaseintentservice an intent service and that will also be killed by android in some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android will kill services after some time, to resolve memory issues. It's not a good thing to always run your application in background, since it will consume memory and processing power.

1. You have got the wrong idea. **GMail and Yahoo are not polling** for new mail, they are using **Push Notification** mechanism, more precisely *Google Cloud Messaging or GCM*. Push Notifications can be received in the background, and once they receive a push notification, they sync the app.
2. **BBM** *(BlackBerry messenger) didn't use GCM, as they relied on BlackBerry servers*. So they ran the application in the background without getting killed. This is done by always showing non swipeable notification. Someway with notification, you could run a service in background without getting it killed.

According to AndroidHeadlines

> You may want to leave it persistent if you want to use BBM. In Android
>   4.3, Google has begun fighting apps that suck down battery and stay alive without you knowing. It now requires any app that wants to run
>   in the background to place a persistent icon in your notification.
>   Hence the BBM icon. Doing this allows that particular app to never be
>   closed.

3. **Surely google will kill any service if the device runs out of memory or new services are running in background.**

Comment: Ok. But push notification is done by gcmintentservice, which is an intent service. So even if we replace the service we are using with gcmintentservice, the likelihood of that being killed by android will be the same? But we don't see yahoo and gmail notifications getting stopped after some time. So why notifications of our app is being killed? Is there any priority we can set for our service.

Comment: "To receive simple downstream messages, use a service that extendsGcmListenerService to handle messages captured by GcmReceiver. GcmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver, guaranteeing that the CPU is awake so that your listener service can complete its task." - GCM Docs

Comment: The Gcmbaseintentservice is not showing as a seperate service in settings. And even if we kill the app, we are receiving notifications. So I guess this method of receiving the notification will always work. It will not be like android will kill the service in some time and we will stop receiving cloud updates.